# Cassandra query with equals operator on timestamp column not working

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I have created a table as follows in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE sp.status(
ams text,
load_start_time timestamp,
file_path text,
file_timestamp timestamp,
host text,
load_end_time timestamp,
records_ignored int,
records_imported int,
records_in_file int,
status text,
PRIMARY KEY (ams, load_start_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (load_start_time DESC)
```

I want to select a row from a specific date. When I use the > operator everything works as expected. But if I use the = operator I get no data back.

```
SELECT * FROM sp.status WHERE ams = 'RRG' AND load_start_time='2016-01-20 10:10:27' allow filtering;
```

There is in the database a row with that value for load_start_time and it is returned if in the above query I replace = with > for load_start_time.

Can someone explain why would this be the case ?

I actually need this for a DELETE statement and there I cannot use range operators, only =.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you INSERT the rows using `dateOf(now())` or with another method containing millisecond precision?  TIMESTAMPs will store milliseconds, but will *not* display it.  Check this example:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.timestamptest (
    userid text,
    activetime timestamp,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, activetime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activetime ASC)


INSERT INTO timestamptest (userid,activetime,value) VALUES ('d',dateof(now()),'value1');
INSERT INTO timestamptest (userid,activetime,value) VALUES ('d','2016-01-22 14:57:54+0000','value2');
SELECT userid, value, activetime, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(activetime)) 
  FROM timestamptest WHERE userid='d';


 userid | value  | activetime               | system.blobasbigint(system.timestampasblob(activetime))
--------+--------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      d | value2 | 2016-01-22 14:57:54+0000 |                           1453474674000
      d | value1 | 2016-01-22 14:57:54+0000 |                           1453474674912

(2 rows)
```

By wrapping activetime in the `blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob())` nested functions, I can see that there are milliseconds present for the time entered via `dateOf(now())` (912), but not for the time entered as text.  As you are finding out, this can become problematic when needing to accomplish an in-place update or delete.

Try using `blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob())` to see if the milliseconds are there, and then add those milliseconds to the timestamp value for your DELETE operation. ex:

```
DELETE FROM timestamptest WHERE userid='d' AND activetime='2016-01-22 14:57:54.912+0000';
```

Comment: You are right. I also thought milliseconds were the problem at start. I am using Dbeaver to access Cassandra. I inspected my timestamp field and it did not show any sign that it stores milliseconds. But your method showed that it does as you said. I added the ms and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @dragosb Awesome!  Glad I could help.

Comment: Your answer totally saved my day in a case where 'SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT N' would show results, but asking for a specific entry returned nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's caused by different time zones. Try to include your zone in the statement like `...AND load_start_time='2016-01-20 10:10:27.000+0200'`

Comment: I thought of this but i tested with the > operator on the second level so I know exactly what date is correct to input

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "unable to coerce '2016-04-06 13:06:11.534000' to a  formatted date (long)" error, although, the timestamp column actually stores milliseconds in all versions, there seem to be some differences in how you can query based on the version:

Cassandra <=2.1 does not seem to support milliseconds in query: yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html

Whereas >=3.0 supports it: yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ffffffZ
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html

I verified being able to select/insert in a newer cluster but not in old cluster using my IDE connected on 9160 Thrift port, have not yet tried on cqlsh:

```
INSERT INTO "sp.status"("ams", "load_start_time")
    VALUES('RRG', '2018-05-01T16:57:18.123+0200')
;

-- same with select, works on new cluster but not old
SELECT * FROM sp.status WHERE ams = 'RRG' AND load_start_time='2018-05-01T16:57:18.123+0200'
;
```

The driver seems to be able to map a java date and store milliseconds in both old and new cluster though.

> =Cassandra 2.1 cqlsh uses native binary protocol (9042), previous versions use thrift (9160) although this should not change.